# Select from sqlite_master locks database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm using QT with Sqlite3.
When i do the

```
Select name from database.sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"
```

My database locks. if run any other query the database works without problem.
It seems the issue is when i run specifically the command to get all the tables in the database.

Here is my sqlite3 method to retrive the data

```
bool SqliteManager::executeSQL(QString query, bool onlyExecute, bool pagination, bool initialize){
    this->query=query;
    sqlite3_stmt *st;
    if(results->size()>0)results->clear();
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, this->query.toStdString().c_str(), -1, &st, 0)==SQLITE_OK){
        if(!onlyExecute){
            this->columnCount=sqlite3_column_count(st);
            //Get Row Count With Original Query
            this->rowCount=this->getRowCount(this->originalQuery, helper::haveLimit(this->originalQuery));
            this->queryRowCount=this->getRowCount(this->query, helper::haveLimit(this->originalQuery));
            cout << "Query count " << this->queryRowCount << " query executed " << this->query.toStdString() << endl;
            //Get Column names and store the data inside the QString vector
            for(int col=0;col<this->columnCount;col++)
                columnNames->push_back(QString((char*)sqlite3_column_name(st, col)));

            //Store the values inside the vector, if you want to get only one row (columnNumber*row) is your index
            while(sqlite3_step(st)==SQLITE_ROW)
                for(int col=0;col<this->columnCount;col++)
                    results->push_back(QString((char*)sqlite3_column_text(st, col)).remove('\r').remove('\n'));
        }
        else{
            bool executed=false;
            int status;
            while((status=sqlite3_step(st))==SQLITE_OK)executed=true;
            cout << "Command executed: " << this->query.toStdString() << endl;
            sqlite3_finalize(st);
            return executed || status == SQLITE_DONE;

        }
        cout << "finalize true" << endl;
        sqlite3_finalize(st);
        return true;

    }
    cout << "prepare error=> " << this->query.toStdString() << endl;
    sqlite3_finalize(st);
    return false;

}
```

The !onlyExecute stores the data into an vector so i can get the fields later.
This is the part of the code called when i do the table listing.
For the insert (i run after) the else is where the insert is ran.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you open your connection without any filename and just attach it later your sqlite_master is not locked for write.